# Extract seconds from interval table / Cast record to interval?

Tags: postgresql, extract

Im getting interval times via:

```
SELECT time_col - lag(time_col) OVER (ORDER BY whatever) 
FROM myTable where conditions
```

This returns a table like this:

```
00:00:38
00:05:10
00:02:05
...
```

I want to have the time in seconds like this:

```
 38
 310
 125
 ...
```

Here is my approach:

```
 SELECT EXTRACT(epoch from dt) from (SELECT time_col - lag(time_col) OVER (ORDER BY whatever) FROM myTable where conditions) as dt
```

dt should be the table with the difference times (intervals). However I get the following error:

```
Error:  Function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, record) does not exist
```

So I have to cast record (the table 'dt') to interval? How do I do that? Or is this completely wrong? Sorry Im new to database queries....

Comment: When posting a follow-up question please link back to the previous question for context. (Use the "share" button to get the link). Remember, **always include your exact PostgreSQL version in every question**. (+1 this time for including the exact error and query, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either this

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch from dt)
from (
    SELECT time_col - lag(time_col) OVER (ORDER BY whatever) dt
    FROM myTable
    where conditions
) as dt
```

Or this

```
SELECT
    extract(epoch from time_col - lag(time_col) OVER (ORDER BY whatever))
FROM myTable
where conditions
```

Comment: So i was very close. Can you explain me the second 'dt'? We select the time and name this column dt. In addition to that the whole result table is named dt? I dont get this part

Comment: @Anonymous It is the same as `SELECT EXTRACT(epoch from dt.dt)`