# SQL query: how do results get retrieved via "any" in own columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, any

Another SQL question. I have the following query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch from dt) as diff
from (
     SELECT time_col - lag(time_col) OVER dt
     FROM myTable where elementID=1234
 ) as dt
```

This calculates the time difference and I get e.g. the following result table for `ElementID` 1234:

```
34
345
6
2
...
```

However I want to do this for every element ID that is stored in the table `elementTable`. Here is my approach:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch from dt) as diff
from (
     SELECT time_col - lag(time_col) OVER dt
     FROM myTable where elementID=any(select elementID from elementTable) 
 ) as dt
```

This is very close to the wanted result, however I get everything in a single column. E.g.

```
34  <- For element id = 1234
345 <- For element id = 1234
6   <- For element id = 1234
2   <- For element id = 1234
83  <- For element id = x
4   <- For element id = x
6   <- For element id = x
...
```

What I want to have is this (ordered in columns by element id):

```
 1234 | x | ...
 ------------------
 34     83  ...
 345    4   ...
 6      6   ...
 2
```

Sorry for bothering you with my SQL questions, I'm trying to learn...

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple `JOIN` instead of the convoluted `ANY` construct:

```
SELECT element_id
      ,EXTRACT(epoch from (time_col - lag(time_col) OVER (ORDER BY something)))
FROM   tbl
JOIN   elementTable USING (element_id);
```

Also, you broke the valid solution [@Clodoaldo provided for your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694830/939860): the `OVER` clause `dt` for the window function was undefined in your query.

To get the result you are asking for, look into the `crosstab()` function of the [`tablefunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) module. More info here:
[Sum by month and put months as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598112/sum-by-month-and-put-months-as-columns/16598510#16598510)

#### Dynamic number of columns

"Dynamic" makes this a lot harder, since SQL wants to know the resulting columns beforehand. I covered the topic comprehensively in this related answer:
[Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

If an array instead of individual columns is good enough for you, look at the answer to the same question [by @Clodoaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15513319#15513319), or, for more explanation, the chapter "Variable number of columns sharing the same type" in this related answer:
[Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. You are right I forgot the '()' behind the over as i have no further clauses. Nevertheless I do not manage to get crosstab using. I also found this site: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/14-CrossTab-Queries-in-PostgreSQL-using-tablefunc-contrib.html that is very similar to your example. However I dont know how to set up a crosstab-query for a dynamic range (in my case element_id). All the examples have fix values (e.g. Jan, Feb, ... Dec). Could you provide me an example? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Anonymous: How dynamic is your range? I added more to my answer.